# Python Selenium Chrome redirecting to slow and returning nothing

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am automating one hospital application, need to get document by customer id, on first 2 pages where in i am filling details automation working fine but after 
clicking on SUBMIT to get details, chrome becomes too slow and returns blank penal after 3-5 minutes, manually all is working well.

Python 2.7
Selenium 3.13
Chrome Driver 2.4
Chrome Version 67

Manual Behaviour - Screen 1 : Login -- Screen2 : Validate patient by name and addmassion date and click SET--Screen3 : downlaod reports. all are woring successful.

Automation Behaviour - Screen 1- Login Successful - Screen 2 Details Typed clicked on SET --Screen 3: page is keep loading for 3/4 minutes and returns a blank page.

Error Chrome Message Popup comes just before screen 3 loading as :-

> Error occured while processing the request at server -  -1

```
> from selenium import webdriver
> 
> from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
> 
> from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
> 
> from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
> 
> import time
> 
> options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
> 
> options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\hitesh
> kumar\\AppData\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
> 
> driver= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chrome
> driver\\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=options)
> 
> driver.get("http://10.**.***.12/****/WBLogin.aspx")
> 
> select_searchby_from_list =
> 
    Select(driver.find_element_by_name("$ddlFieldName01")).select_by_visible_text("patient_number")
> 
>     patient_number = "OPD21062018823"
> 
>     txt_patient_number = driver.find_element_by_name("$txtFieldValue01").send_keys(patient_number)
> 
>     select_department_from_list=Select(driver.find_element_by_name("ddlFieldName02")).select_by_visible_text("OPD")
> 
>     DOA = "21062018"
> 
>     txt_DOA = driver.find_element_by_name("$txtFieldValue02").send_keys(DOA)
> 
>     btn_set=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ucCriteria_txtFieldValue02"]').click()
```

Comment: Update the question with the error stack trace

Comment: there was no error as such only only popup message like "Error occured while processing the request at server - -1"

Comment: Thank you @Debanjan  for your response , Actually find_element was able to find the SET tab but was not getting clicked by any reason, so value typed were not taken in function to search the document  , and just after that clicking SEARCH so there was no value going in session,,, I have changed the element to find_element_by name from find_element_by_expath. then all steps worked well,

Comment: Alright. Let me know if you face any difficulty.